# NoReverseMatch at /1/stationary-item-1/ Reverse for 'addreview' with no arguments not found

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Recently I'm working to make an e-commerce website using django, my problem is the views are stuck on an error says that the reverse for `addreview` function requires id, but whenever i assign id to that field, it shows me this type of error.I am stucked at this point for hours.

I am beginner to django, and I dont know that how the parameters are included,

Please help me,

Here is my code,

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django import forms

class Category(models.Model):
    Categories = [
        ("Pens & Stationary", "Pens & Stationary"),
        ("Arts & Crafts", "Arts & Crafts"),
        ("Notebooks & Fullscapes", "Notebooks & Fullscapes"),
        ("Files & Folders", "Files & Folders"),
        ("Others", "Others")
    ]
    cname = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Categories)
    cicon = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="fa fa-lg")
    cslug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cname

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('store:product_list_by_category',args = [self.cslug])

# Create your models here."""
class Product(models.Model):
    pimg = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics',null = True, blank=True)
    pname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pslug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, db_index=True, unique=False)
    pprice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    pstock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    pcats = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pdesc = models.TextField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.pname

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('store:product_details',args = [self.id,self.pslug])

class ExploreItems(models.Model):
    eitname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    eitimg = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    eitdesc = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.eitname


class Review(models.Model):
    rsummary = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    mreview = models.TextField()
    rproduct = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ruser = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ruser_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rrating = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("index:addreview",args=[self.id])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rsummary


class LoginUser(models.Model):
    user_status = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="logged_user",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_status.username
```

views.py

```
import time
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth
from .models import Product,ExploreItems,Category
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404,HttpResponse
from django.core.paginator import Paginator,PageNotAnInteger,EmptyPage
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Review
# Create your views here.

cats = Category.objects.all()
items = Product.objects.all()
exitems = ExploreItems.objects.all()
users = User.objects.all()

def index(request):
    return render(request,"index.html",{'exitems':exitems})

def product(request):
    return render(request,"product.html")

def cart(request):
    return render(request,"cart.html")

def payment(request):
    return render(request,"payment.html")

def login(request):
    return render(request,"login.html")

def product_list(request, cat_slug = None):
    cat = None
    price_range = request.POST.get('range_price')

    object_list = Product.objects.filter(pstock=True)
    if cat_slug:
        cat = get_object_or_404(Category, cslug = cat_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(pcats = cat)
    elif price_range:
        object_list = object_list.filter(pprice__lte=price_range)

    #object_list = object_list.filter(pprice__range=(0, price_range))
    pg = Paginator(object_list, 6)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        items = pg.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        items = pg.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        items = pg.page(pg.num_pages)
    return render(request,"products.html", {'items':items, 'cats':cats, 'cat':cat,'page':page})

def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Product,id = id,pslug = slug, pstock = True)
    return render(request,"product.html", {'item':item})

def register(request):
    global fname
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fname = request.POST.get('fname')
        lname = request.POST.get('lname')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        emdmain = request.POST.get('email_domain')
        uname = emdmain.split('@')[0]
        hno = request.POST.get('hno')
        street = request.POST.get('street')
        route = request.POST.get('route')
        city = request.POST.get('city')
        zipc = request.POST.get('zipc')
        desh = request.POST.get('desh')
        psswd = request.POST.get('psswd')
        cpsswd = request.POST.get('cpsswd')

        if psswd != cpsswd :
            return HttpResponse(request,"Password Didn't Match")
            return redirect("/")

        elif User.objects.filter(username = uname).exists():
            return HttpResponse("Username is already taken !!!!")
            return redirect("/")

        elif User.objects.filter(email=emdmain).exists():
            return HttpResponse(request,"E-mail is already taken !!!!")
            return redirect("/")

        else:
            user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=fname, last_name=lname, username=uname, email=emdmain, password=psswd)
            user.save()

            return HttpResponse(request,'User created!! Username : {}'.format(uname))

def user_login(request):
    global user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_uname = request.POST.get('uname')
        user_psswd = request.POST.get('psswd')
        keep_logged = request.POST.get('keep_logged')


        user = auth.authenticate(username = user_uname,password = user_psswd)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Invalid Credentials!!!!')
            return redirect('login')

    return  HttpResponse(request, "User Logged In")

def user_logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)

    return HttpResponse(request,"User logged out successfully")



def addreview(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rsummary = request.POST.get('rsummary')
        mreview = request.POST.get('mreview')
        prating = request.POST.get('product_rating')

        Review(rsummary=rsummary,mreview=mreview,rrating=prating,ruser_id=request.user.id,rproduct_id=id,ruser_name=request.user.first_name).save()
        return HttpResponse("Done !!!")
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name = "homepage"),
    path('store/',views.product_list, name = "product_list"),
    path('ajax/store/',views.product_list,name = "product_list_by_price"),
    path('<slug:cat_slug>/',views.product_list,name = 'product_list_by_category'),
    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/',views.product_detail, name = 'product_details'),
    #url(r'^(?P<cat_slug>[-\w]+)/$',views.product_list,name = 'product_list_by_category'),
    #url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',views.product_detail,name = 'product_details'),
    path('product',views.product),
    #path('cart',views.cart),
    path('payment',views.payment),
    path('login',views.login, name = "login_page"),
    path('register', views.register, name ='register'),
    path('user_login', views.user_login, name = "user_login"),
    path('user_logout',views.user_logout,name = "user_logout"),
    path('<int:id>/',views.addreview, name = "addreview"),
]
```

My error logs

```
Internal Server Error: /1/stationary-item-1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\django p\GSStationary\Stationary\views.py", line 67, in product_detail
    return render(request,"product.html", {'item':item})
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'addreview' with no arguments not found. 3 pattern(s) tried: ['payment/
(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', 'product/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', 'store/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks:)

Comment: You write `rproduct_id=id`, but there is no `id` that you obtain, so it falls back on the builtin `id` function, but that is a function, and not the id of a `rproduct` (or anything else).

Comment: So, what do i do ?? , Is there any solution ?

Comment: well how do you pass the `product_id` to the view?

Comment: I have passed the parameter, now this error generated, I have updated question with error

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here:

```
def addreview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rsummary = request.POST.get('rsummary')
        mreview = request.POST.get('mreview')
        prating = request.POST.get('product_rating')

        Review(rsummary=rsummary,mreview=mreview,rrating=prating,rproduct_id=id,ruser_name=request.user.first_name).save()
        return HttpResponse("Done !!!")
```

There is no `id` variable in function scope. But `id` is a [valid global python function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).
To fix it you must define `id` variable before usage.